# Separate background thread pointing on an old ViewModel after restating app

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, background, viewmodel

I have an app that do BLE scan on the background and alert the user by playing a sound and shows up a popup with a button to snooze. So if the user click on that button the app will stop playing the alert sound and dismiss the popup for a while (default duration is one minute)
So if the app in background mode it still works and can play the alert sound and then when I reopen the app by clicking on the service notification it shows the popup

So I'm calculating the spent time after the user click on dismiss button on a separate thread using some variables in the viewModel because I need them in other place.

Here is my code

```
Thread {
            while (true) {
                val previous = tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.stopAlertingAt.value
                val durationMin = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("dismiss_duration", "1")!!.toInt()
                val diff = (Date().time - previous!!.time) / 1000 / 60
                if ( diff  >= durationMin  && tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.isStopAlerting() ) {
                    tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.setStopAlerting(false)
                }
            }
        }.start()
```

The code above is to check always if the duration past to alert again the user

```
    binding.btnDismiss.setOnClickListener {
            tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.stopAlertingAt.value = Date()
            tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.setStopAlerting(true)
    }
```

So the problem here is when I close the app and open it again the line code below will point always on the last value before I close the app

```
        val previous = tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.stopAlertingAt.value
```

But here it change correct the value

```
    tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.stopAlertingAt.value = Date()
```

So if I understood correctly is that the background thread still use the mode ViewModel with the old value and I can't figure out how to fix that.

I'm using Koin Module for my viewModels

Comment: Did you try using tagDetailsAlertsViewModel.stopAlertingAt.postValue(Date()) ?

Comment: After I open the app for the second time the value change for stopAlertingAt but the get is pointing on the last value before closing the app